# How to add custom column dynamically in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm stacked to add Custom columns dynamically in ag-grid.
I have tried following approach.

```
additionalCol = { field:'SOME RANDOM', headerName: 'SOME RANDOM' };
$scope.gridOptions.columnApi.addValueColumn(additionalCol);
```

I have also tried

```
$scope.columns.push(additionalCol);
$scope.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

but didn't get success.
I even tried to add columns that exist in Data but failed.
Below is Image for what I am trying.
[image]

As shown in image "% dev" is Custom column which I need to add dynamically with dynamically calculated values.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
var columnDefs = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs;
columnDefs.push({ field:'SOME RANDOM', headerName: 'SOME RANDOM'});
$scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

Comment: I have this error "cannot find namespace $scoope". I am using Angular.