# How to dynamically add/remove columns from a list in ag-grid community version?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using the plain **JavaScript version** of ag-grid in my web application.
The ag-grid version is

> ag-grid-community v19.0.0

I tried the solution mention in [similar question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595285/how-to-add-custom-column-dynamically-in-ag-grid) . However this does not maintain pagination.

Essentially I would like to replicate the enterprise feature of **tool-panel-column option** with this version of ag-grid, which maintains pagination as well.